# Batch attachment extractor add-on for Thunderbird

Tags: open-source, thunderbird, email-attachments

I'm a little surprised this isn't a more commonly needed feature: I'd like to remove attachments from my old emails in Thunderbird.

I used to use [AttachmentExtractor](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/attachmentextractor/), which saved a lot of remote and local disk space, but it is now incompatible. [FiltaQuilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/) seems to be the replacement, but that looks to be incompatible with new versions of Thunderbird.

Is there an add-on or built-in attachment extractor for several emails at once? Doing this one at a time is not an option.

Comment: Been using AttachmentExtractor for years, but it no longer works as of THunderbird 60.2.1. Would love to find a replacement as this has seriously affected my workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **AttachmentExtractor** by Andrew Williamson: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/attachmentextractor/

Although it is a really (as in really...last updated in 2011 and listed as compatible with Thunderbird 16...) old and unmaintained add-on, it still works perfectly for me (though there are some complaints that it is not working for some).

It is very easy and simple to use. Select all the messages you want attachments from (you can filter and Select All), then right-click and choose the option you want to use:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screengrab, and I'd love to accept this as an answer, but the add on is no longer working for me. I used to use it, but it no longer works on recent installs of Thunderbird on both OSX and Ubuntu.